# Translation for error message

Tags: i18n-l10n

I created a feedback form using the Webform module and the  Internationalization module for the English and the Japan version.

*Feedback is required.* is translated as *「ご意見・ご感想」は必須項目です。* where the translation for *Feedback* is *ご意見・ご感想*. I need to show *「本文メッセージ」は必須項目です。* as error message.

How can I do this?

Comment: You want the error message to be `「本文メッセージ」は必須項目です。` but the translation for feedback is `ご意見・ご感想`?  Why not just change the feedback translation to `本文メッセージ`?

Comment: No I need feedback translation as ご意見・ご感想 and error message as 「本文メッセージ」は必須項目です。

Answer (score 1):

By default, Drupal (and Webform) show the error message as `Field_name is required`, so if you want to show an error message that uses something other than `field_name`, you will have to override/write your own validation function.

The [Webform Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation) module may be of assistance here, particularly the [code examples for custom validation hooks.](https://www.drupal.org/node/908600)

P.S. "本文メッセージ" is probably a mistranslation; it most likely should be flipped ("メッセージ本文", "message body").